# Why can the ball travel at the same speed to the left like the toy car and at the same time travel vertically upwards?

Tags: kinematics

Imagine a toy car travelling at constant speed to the left. Balls are projected vertically upward one at a time, at 1-second intervals.

Edited question : Why is the ball travelling at the same horizontal speed and in the same direction as which the toy car is travelling whilst travelling vertically upwards when projected by the toy car?

Or

Why can the ball travel at the same speed to the left like the toy car and at the same time travel vertically upwards?

The 2 questions above mean the same thing.

Comment: What does vertically upward to the left mean?

Comment: Are the balls shot out at an angle $0<\theta<90$, or are they shot straight up? The "vertically upwards to the left" is not at all clear what you're trying to say/mean.

Comment: Edited the question. They are shot straight up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the ball have the same constant horizontal speed to the left even if it is projected vertically upwards?

All balls have the horizontal speed of the car as long as they are transported by the car. When they are fired upwardly by a gun their vertical speed (that was initially zero) modifies but nothing changes their horizontal speed (if all this show happens in vacuum).

A day to day example, you are in a metro train traveling at 72 km/h and you throw a ball perpendicular to the roof. After 1 sec, the ball comes back and falls into your hand also, in the meantime, the train travels 20 m horizontally. The explanation is that you and the ball also travel 20 m horizontally. The horizontal speed of the ball is all the time 72 km/h while going to the roof and coming back.